# Validation of Entry Widget in tkinter using python

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to validate an entry widget in tkinter using python. I am expecting an input like 5.0e-7, 1.0e-5 so on. Please see the crude code.

```
class Validated(ttk.Entry):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.configure(
        validate='all',
        validatecommand=(self.register(self.validate), '%P'),
        )
  def validate(self, input, **kwargs):
    if any([(input not in '-1234567890e.')]):
      return True
    elif input is "":
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter validation of Entry widgets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936033/tkinter-validation-of-entry-widgets-in-python)

Comment: I just noticed after giving my answer that you posted the same question three times in the last 6 hours, which i find quite rude. One of them had my exact strategy. I think you have to think a little for yourself on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
import re

def is_valid(input_number):
    return bool(re.match(r"\d+.\d+e[-+]\d+", input_number))

input_number = "5.0e-8"
valid = is_valid(input_number)
print(valid)  # returns True
input_number = "5.0ae-8"
valid = is_valid(input_number)
print(valid)  # returns False
```

Explanation of regex `\d+.\d+e[-+]\d+`: `\d` matches one digit, `\d+` matches any number of digits, `[-+]` matches `+` or `-`, `.` and `e` are hardcoded. You can also test your regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/).